# Given a matrix mat of size 3 x 3. Find the maximum numbers from each row, say N1, N2 and N3

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given a matrix mat of size 3 x 3. Find the maximum numbers from each row, say N1, N2 and N3. Result in a matrix by adding:

```
import numpy as np
mat = np.array([[10,5,9],
                [2,20,6],
                [8,3,30]]).reshape(3,3)
```

- N1 to the upper half elements of mat
- N2 to the main diagonal elements of mat
- N3 to the lower half elements of mat

**my code:**

```
import numpy as np
mat = np.array([[10,5,9],
                [2,20,6],
                [8,3,30]]).reshape(3,3)

max_list = np.max(mat, axis=0)
N1 = max_list[0]
N2 = max_list[1]
N3 = max_list[2]

z_mat = np.zeros((3, 3), dtype=np.int32)
N1_mat = z_mat[0:2, 2:] = N1
```

I was stuck here

Comment: The logic is unclear, what is the exact expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.tri` and `np.eye` to create masks for the different regions you need. `np.select` is useful to fill in the right values!

```
upper = ~np.tri(3, dtype=bool)
diag = np.eye(3, dtype=bool)
lower = np.tri(3, k=-1)

values = np.select([upper, diag, lower], mat.max(axis=0))

out = mat + values
```

Outputs:

```
>>> upper
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False]])
>>> diag
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True]])
>>> lower
array([[False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False]])
>>> values
array([[20, 10, 10],
       [30, 20, 10],
       [30, 30, 20]])
>>> out
array([[30, 15, 19],
       [32, 40, 16],
       [38, 33, 50]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that you mean the [upper and lower triangular matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix) when you say "upper half" and "lower half"

You've figured out how to get the rowwise maximum correctly. Next, you want to:

- Add `N1` to the upper half elements of `mat`. You can use [`np.triu_indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html) to get the correct indices and add `N1` to those indices:

```
upper_indices = np.triu_indices(mat.shape[0], 1)
mat[upper_indices] += N1
```

The second argument to `triu_indices` specifies the offset above the diagonal where you want to start the triangular matrix.

- Add `N2` to the diagonal elements of `mat`. You can use [`np.diag_indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag_indices.html)

```
diag_indices = np.diag_indices(mat.shape[0])
mat[diag_indices] += N2
```

- Add `N3` to the lower half elements of `mat`. You can use [`np.tril_indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril_indices.html) to get the correct indices and add `N3` to those indices:

```
lower_indices = np.tril_indices(mat.shape[0], -1)
mat[lower_indices] += N3
```

The second argument to `tril_indices` also specifies the offset *above* the diagonal where you want to start the triangular matrix, so it needs to be `-1` to start the triangular matrix below the diagonal
This results in the following `mat`:

```
array([[30, 15, 19],
       [32, 40, 16],
       [38, 33, 50]])
```